# How do I install snort on RPi?

Tags: raspbian, debian

I was trying to install snort and everytime I encounter a problem I tried to follow this link http://www.snort.org/assets/167/IDS_deb_snort_howto.pdf but then I realized that it cannot be applied on ARM architecture !

Comment: How does sudo apt-get install snort fail?

Comment: the problem is with the dotdeb packages !! it doesn't support ARM architecture only i386 and amd !

Comment: Are you saying that you did a sudo apt-get install snort and it failed?  Which distribution?

Comment: the problem is with dotdeb packages !!

Comment: the current distribution is Debian/Raspbian.

Comment: I think I see your issue, ignore what that guide says about adding sources, keep the default ones which have ARM ports of MySQL and PHP.

Comment: this is what I did thx @Dan

Answer (score 2):

There's a Raspberry Pi [security tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Firewall-and-Intrusion-Detection-Syst/?ALLSTEPS) based on ArchLinux, that includes step 13 "Snort installation".

Basically all you have to do is:

```
$ sudo pacman -S snort
```

Please, follow the instruction as close as you can.

[image: snort logo image]

Comment: this is the half of the answer thanks :) ... and what about Debian OS (Raspbian) ?

Comment: for raspbian you're supposed to use `sudo apt-get install snort`, however I could not find any tutorial that I can recommend.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install snort
```

works for me on a Raspbian Pi.

I'd be amazed if it didn't also work on my Debian Pi (but I can't be bothered to try and see).

Answer (score 1):

@lenik's answer would be correct, if not for the AUR repository to not have an ARMv6 build available for snort, which is what we need for the raspberry pi.
This topic describes how to build the needed package yourself with the source tarball from the AUR repository:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=36314&p=305583

Building this on the Pi will take about 1 hour, be warned :-)

I imagine the Raspbian repository has the same issue.
I'm still setting up everything myself, but am wondering whether it will work reasonably in the end. Since no one seems to be making Pi-compatible ARMv6 packages for Snort, perhaps it will just be too slow to run it...

Answer (score -4):

I am writing an educational Guide about Snort on Raspeberry PI, and Used two tutorials that worked fine for me:

Tut 1 [Installing SNORT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptIzGv1b9GQ) by (Computer and Network Security)

Using sudo aptitude install snort <---- easy way

TUt 2 downloading all the packages from snort's website and compiling them <---Long way
  Part 1 [Snort Install on Ubuntu 14.04LTS Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVvS8Peb2fY)
  Part 2 [Snort Install on Ubuntu 14.04LTS Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Epsb8cL6HvE)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.